# Only the hosting computer can access SVN

Tags: svn

I used VisualSVN Server to create a repository on a windows 7 desktop. But I can only access this server from my account, and only from this computer. (I work in university so I can use my account on any computer in my lab). On any other computers, I can't even access the repository from browser, not to mention Tortoises svn.

I think this has something to do with the firewall/router settings, but I don't know where to start off. I tried to turn off my windows firewall, it didn't work. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Start by reading Chapter 6 of the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html), which explains how to properly configure your server. We can't help with configuring your network settings, as this isn't the appropriate site for that type of question. Using SVN is on-topic here, configuring your server to allow access is not.

Comment: And after migration show in question at least httpd.conf of VisualSVN Server (SVN-location part) and output of any failed command (`svn ls URL` f.e)

Comment: @KenWhite the SVN book you recommended is a nice way to start with. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. VisualSVN Server exposes your repositories via HTTP(S). The default port for HTTP is 80 (8080) and for HTTPS is 443 (8443) so it makes sense to check which port VisualSVN Server listens to and whether it's open in firewall and router settings.
2. If your machine is member of you university's Active Directory domain, then you have to provide domain user accounts with access to your repos via VisualSVN Server Manager console. Otherwise other users will constantly "Access Denied" error when attempting to access your repos.